# Syntax highlighter for JEditorPane, font change produces offset bug

Tags: java, macos, swing, jpanel, jeditorpane

I'm using a JEditorPane within a JScrollPane. I'm initialising the code as follows:

```
jsArea = new JEditorPane();
JScrollPane scrPane = new JScrollPane(jsArea);
scrPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 710));
scrPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 710));
scrPane.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(1600, 1600));
scrPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder (Color.white, 3));
jsArea.setContentType("text/javascript");
jsArea.setFont(Font.getFont("Arial"));
content.add(scrPane, c);
```

The editor works as expected, except when i type something like the following:

> ctx.arc(1,2,3,4,5,6)

What happens here is the cursor (believing it is at the end of the line) hovers over "5" and movement of the cursor isn't consistant with the text being displayed. It works fine on the default font, but I need to use Arial.

**Note I'm using a [syntax highlighter](https://code.google.com/p/jsyntaxpane/), too, which *could* be the problem.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Works fine for me Windows 7 x64 java7u10

Comment: For me too,which platform you are using?

Comment: I'm using Mac OSX 10.8.2. I've also added that I'm using a syntax highlighter. Not sure this should cause any problems though.

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174070/wrapping-html-text-in-a-jeditorpane-inside-a-jscrollpane) may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [for plain EditorKit have to use `text/html` or `text/plain` or `text/rtf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setContentType%28java.lang.String%29) , not `setContentType("text/javascript");` (usage for `JSON` or `Servlet`)

> If there is a charset definition specified as a parameter of the
>   content type specification, it will be used when loading input streams
>   using the associated EditorKit. For example if the type is specified
>   as `text/html;` charset=EUC-JP the content will be loaded using the
>   EditorKit registered for text/html and the Reader provided to the
>   EditorKit to load unicode into the document will use the EUC-JP
>   charset for translating to unicode. If the type is not recognized, the
>   content will be loaded using the EditorKit registered for plain text,
>   `text/plain`.

- todays `HTML in Java` is reduced for support `HTML<=3.2`  (partially supporting css & styles)

EDIT

- [JSyntaxPane Screenshots showing syntax hightlighter for text/javascript](http://i1-mac.softpedia-static.com/screenshots/JSyntaxPane_3.png) as parameter for `HightLighter`