# Add HTML in JEditorPane in Java Swing

Tags: java, html, swing, jeditorpane

I would like to add HTML in my `JEditorPane` but the text is not displayed correctly.
Also, when the text's height is greater that the editor's height,
the the cursor goes to the last line of the scroll Pane.

My code is as follows:

```
    JPanel JPInfo = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPInfo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Information"));
    editorPaneInfo = new JEditorPane();
    editorPaneInfo.setEditable(false);
    editorPaneInfo.setText("<html><p style=\"color:green\"> Test Test </p></html>");
    JScrollPane editorScrollPaneInfo = new JScrollPane(editorPaneInfo);
    editorScrollPaneInfo.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    JPInfo.add(editorScrollPaneInfo,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

**SOLVED:**
I added the following line before setText

```
 editorPaneInfo.setContentType("text/html");
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Try describing a) What you expected to happen b) What actually happened, and for utility c) Why you expected (a) to happen. Screenshots might help.

Comment: I was expecting the text to be green but now I solved my problem: I visited the following link [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174070/wrapping-html-text-in-a-jeditorpane-inside-a-jscrollpane] and i added `editorPaneInfo.setContentType("text/html");` in my code, now everything is working now!

Comment: Please answer your own question, or delete it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was solved:

I added the following line before .setText()

```
editorPaneInfo.setContentType("text/html");
```